# Save point issue

Tags: apex, savepoint

Hi I have controller which is creating the parent records and we are calling some different controller to create child records, want to roll back all  if any of the child record get fail how can we achieve this.

```
//controller to create parent child records record
 public class mainClass{

    List<Account> lstAccount{get;set;}
    List<FirstChild__c> lstfirstChild{get;set;}
    List<SecondChild__c> lstSecondChild{get;set;}
    List<ThirdChild__c> lstThirdChild{get;set;}

    public void createparent(){
        parentcontroller parent=new parentcontroller();
        lstAccount=parent.createParentRecords(); //this method will call the parentcontroller and there itself it will create parent record and return the created parent records
    }

    public void createFirstChil(){
        firstChildcontroller first=new firstChildcontroller();
        lstfirstChild=first.createFirstChildRecord(lstAccount); // This method will create first child records
    }

    public void createFirstChil(){
        secondChildcontroller first=new secondChildcontroller();
        lstSecondChild=first.createSecondChildRecord(lstAccount);// This method will create first child records
    }
    public void createFirstChil(){
        thirdchildcontroller first=new thirdchildcontroller();
        lstThirdChild=first.createThirdChildRecord(lstAccount);// This method will create first child records
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `insert`, you can just catch any exceptions and rollback:

```
System.Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
try
{
    createParentRecords();
    createFirstChildren();
    ...
}
catch(DMLException ex)
{
    Database.rollback(sp);
}
```

If you are using `Database.Insert`, so it does not throw an exception on error, you will need to return the results of the save to the caller.  The simplest way to do this would be to define your creation methods like:

```
public boolean createParent()
{
    ...
    List<Database.SaveResult> results = Database.insert(records, true);
    for(Database.SaveResult result : results)
    {
        if (!result.isSuccess())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Your child creation methods would follow the same pattern.  You can then run them in your calling class with:

```
public void insertRecords()
{
    System.Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    if (!createParent() || !createFirstChildren() || !createSecondChildren())
    {
        Database.rollback(sp);
    }
}
```